Getting attribute information to call getattr() and setattr()
I'm creating a Pygame helper library, and one thing I've implemented is an Animator, which can ease any numerical attribute between two values.
To add an 'animation' to my Animator, you call:
animator.addAnimation(object, attribute, newValue, duration=1, easingFunction=easeLinear, type=float)

The reason for passing both the object and the string attribute name is because my implementation uses getattr and setattr.
My question: is there any way for me to simply pass the attribute directly to my addAnimation method and then determine the object name and the string attribute behind the scenes?
i.e. I'd like to be able to simply call:
animator.addAnimation(sprite.position.x, ...)

rather than
animator.addAnimation(sprite.position, 'x', ...)

Happy to do things a different/better way if there is one. My main requirement is for the API to be as intuitive as possible.
Thanks.

I think the pythonic way is to pass the getter/setter as a lambda. But if you need both the getter and setter, it can get a bit messy. Can you show us how the addAnimation method is implemented so we can get a clearer picture?

Hi, yes the implementation is here: https://github.com/rik-cross/pygamepal/blob/main/src/pygamepal/animator.py and uses getattr to store the current value on initialisation of a new animation, and then setattr to update the value.

No. A function argument is just an expression that gets evaluated down to a single value, which then gets passed to the function. There's no way for the function to know which variable, attributes, or operations the value comes from.

Ok thanks. I wondered whether there was any dunder method (dir etc.) that could give this information. Good to get confirmation that there isn't.
